# Does an MX DNS Record Sub-Domain need to exist as another DNS Record?

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

I am trying to setup a mail server on my Ubuntu server.

In setting up the DNS MX Record for the mail server I am confused.

I have added an MX record for `mail.domain.com` simply because it is the format I generally see in tutorials.

My question is, does `mail.domain.com` need to also exist as an `A` or `CNAME` Record before it can be able to be used as an MX record?

In a terminal if I run `dig mail.domain.com +short` with my domain in quiestion, it does NOT return an IP like it should.  Because of this I am thinking that my `mail.domain.com` MX record is not settup correctly, can someone assist with my question please and thank you.

Below is ALL my DNS records so if it does need to exist as another record, I would be missing it right now!

[image]

Comment: To check your mx record using dig you need to ask for it explicitly - dig mx mail.domain.com.    What does that show?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need an A record that corresponds to the MX record. The MX record designates which host email should be delivered to for the domain and for that you need a host (A) record.

Without over complicating things, if **mail.domain.com** is where email for **domain.com** should be delivered to then the end result should be that a DNS query for the MX record returns mail.domain.com and a DNS query for mail.domain.com returns the ip address of your email server.

Answer (score 5):

> I have added an MX record for mail.domain.com simply because it is the format I generally see in tutorials.

So your email addresses are in the format `user@mail.domain.com`? If your email addresses are intended to be `user@domain.com`, then you need an MX record for `domain.com`

> My question is, does mail.domain.com need to also exist as an A or CNAME Record before it can be able to be used as an MX record?

If the MX record for `mail.domain.com` is, say, `server1.domain.com`, then `server1.domain.com` can be an A record or possibly a CNAME, and even an IP address, but that latter is typically frowned upon.

> In a terminal if I run dig mail.domain.com +short with my domain in quiestion, it does NOT return an IP like it should. Because of this I am thinking that my mail.domain.com MX record is not settup correctly, can someone assist with my question please and thank you.

You should probably share your actual domain name, unless you are contractually bound to not share what you're working on. For example, in your screenshot, you have two MX records, and each record has a different domain, so that means you're expecting to receive mail for two different domains. `domain.com` and `mail.domain.com`.

I think you are a bit confused. =)